# How does shared_ptr<> safely allow casting to bool?

Tags: c++, stl, shared-ptr

I was looking into how `std::tr1::shared_ptr<>` provides the ability to cast to bool.  I've got caught out in the past when trying to create a smart pointer that can be casted to bool as the trivial solution, ie

```
operator bool() {
  return m_Ptr!=0;
}
```

usually ends up being implicitly castable to the pointer type (presumably by type promotion), which is generally undesirable.  Both the boost and Microsoft implementations appear to use a trick involving casting to an `unspecified_bool_type()`.  Can anyone explain how this mechanism works and how it prevents implicit casting to the underlying pointer type?

Comment: All great answers, thanks.  Good to be able to put a name to it too -- hadn't come across the safe bool idiom before.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The technique described in the question is the [safe bool idiom](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/safebool.html).

As of C++11, that idiom is no longer necessary. The modern solution to the problem is to use the `explicit` keyword on the operator:

```
explicit operator bool() {
  return m_Ptr != nullptr;
}
```

Comment: Oh, I knew of the safe bool idiom and recently discovered the `explicit` conversion operators, but I didn't know about this lil' `null_ptr` thingy. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

The trick works like this. You define all this inside your smart pointer type (in this case, `shared_ptr`):

```
private:

  struct Tester
  {
    Tester(int) {}  // No default constructor
    void dummy() {}
  };

  typedef void (Tester::*unspecified_bool_type)();

public:

  operator unspecified_bool_type() const
  {
    return !ptr_ ? 0 : &Tester::dummy;
  }
```

`ptr_` is the native pointer inside the smart pointer class.

As you can see, `unspecified_bool_type` is a `typedef` to a type that cannot be accessed by any external code, since `Tester` is a private struct. But calling code can use this (implicit) conversion to a pointer type and check whether it is null or not. Which, in C++, can be used as a `bool` expression.

Comment: What's up with the `##ModelId`?

Comment: @KennyTM: Sorry, just removed that.

Comment: You need to provide implementations of `!=` and `==` for `Tester::unspecified_bool_type` or you'll allow meaningless comparissons between instances of the class to compile.

Comment: @Joe Gauterin: Why? `Tester::unspecified_bool_type` is just a pointer (a pointer to a function, in fact), you don't need to define such a thing. And there is no problem in comparing those pointers; after all, the comparisons behave as expected.

Comment: @Gorpik: If you `==` compare two instances of a class using the idiom, they'll both implicitly convert to the `unspecified_bool_type`, the comparrison will return whether they both have the same conversion to `unspecified_bool_type`, not whether they are equal.

Comment: No, I mean that for a class to use the safe bool idiom without otherwise altering the behaviour of the class, the `==` and `!=` operators must be defined for the `unspecified_bool_type`.

Comment: But @Joe, the same would happen for *any* implicit conversion operators on the smart-pointer class. This doesn't seem to be anything particular to the special bool type concocted here. If you use `==` to compare smart-pointer objects, and the only way the compiler can satisfy that request is to call the implicit conversion operators and compare the results, what's the harm? Besides, how do you suggest the member-pointer comparison operators be implemented?

Comment: @Rob: Yes, it would happen for any implicit conversion - which is why implicit conversion operators are generally avoided. The harm created by enabling operator `==` accidentally is that an error  previously detectable by the compiler becomes a hard to detect runtime error. See the link in my answer for suggested implementation.

Comment: @Joe Gauterin: If you redefine operators `==` and `!=` for the smart pointer class (in addition to all other operators that work on raw pointers, such as `*` and `->`), you have no problems at all. Comparing two smart pointers will correctly call the comparison operator with no implicit conversions to `unspecified_bool_type` at all.

Comment: @Gorpik: I agree, but the safe bool idiom is useful on things other than smart pointers, so it's important to be aware of that issue.

Answer (score 3):

Usually what it returns is a member pointer. Member pointers can be treated like a `bool` but don't support many of the implicit conversions which `bool` does.